# Inspect state in fun-mode in Quil using the REPL?

Tags: clojure, quil

I'm writing a sketch in Clojure/Quil in fun(ctional)-mode.

Sometimes, I want to be able to inspect what the current `state` holds.

However, when I try to call Quil's `state` from the REPL I get the following:

```
(q/state) ==>
NullPointerException   clojure.core/deref-future (core.clj:2208)
```

Not sure if this is relevant, but the same happens with drawing functions from the REPL:

```
(q/rect 0 0 10 10)
```

How can I get the current state to inspect it in the REPL?

Comment: Can you post some more code, esp. the function that calls `state` and `deref-future`?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which function exactly you are talking about since you do not post code so this is a bit of a blind shot.

You could try to see the `state-atom`:

```
(require '[quil.core :as q])

;; both should do the same

@(q/state-atom)
(q/state) ;; is that what you were doing ?
```

The state function you seem to refer to optionally takes a parameter, [for instance](https://github.com/quil/quil/blob/be03cdeb61e78ecf4d3e09a5fb8e8d3658631816/test/cljc/snippets/environment.cljc#L36), and returns the state-atom when [no parameter](https://github.com/quil/quil/blob/be03cdeb61e78ecf4d3e09a5fb8e8d3658631816/src/cljc/quil/core.cljc#L223) is passed:

```
(q/state :image)
```

In any case, it is generally a good idea to look at the tests of a Clojure library, and the code in this case seems very well documented.

Comment: This question concerns the REPL mostly. Sorry I couldn't clarify this much sooner. I'll try the above though.

Answer (score 1):

In order to call Clojure/Quil functions directly in the REPL, they need to be wrapped with the current sketch:

```
(quil.applet/with-applet hello-quil.core/hello-quil 
  (quil.core/random 10))
```

To access the `state` you can do this:

```
(require '[quil.core :as q])

(quil.applet/with-applet hello-quil.core/hello-quil 
  (q/state))
```

This is taken directly from the Quil wiki: [Dynamic Workflow (for REPL)](https://github.com/quil/quil/wiki/Dynamic-Workflow-%28for-REPL%29)